# What are the requirements for titles in Jamestown?

Tags: jamestown

In Jamestown there are several titles when you complete a level, such as

- field surgeon
- most gutsy
- most deadly
- privateer.

Also, there are some team titles, as

- credit savers
- ...?

While "field surgeon" and "credit savers" are pretty much self-explanatory, "most gutsy" and "most deadly" seem to be a little bit random. Are there some specific requirements in order to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start this off by saying I honestly am not sure, I haven't played Jamestown in a while.

If I remember correctly, when I played with my friend we also tried to figure this out and our conclusion was that most deadly was just whoever killed the most guys, while most gutsy had something to do with getting hit while you are shielded (vaunted?) or it was dying the most.

But this is far from definitive and I agree that it does seem pretty random.

Answer (score -1):

Most Deadly: *Stands for someone being the most dangerous AKA someone who kills the most amount of players and/or someone being feared a lot.*

Most Gutsy: *Stands for someone showing a lot of courage AKA suicidally dying a lot and/or sometimes stands for being tough but not having a great amount of kill.*

Comment: *"someone who kills the most amount of players"*. You're aware that this is a co-op game, right? Also, do you have a source?